# Reading a javascript from DB and adding it to xhtml dynamically

Tags: java, javascript, xhtml

I need to read a javaScript which would reside in a DB table as blob. I neeed read it as bytes from DB and attach that script to  a Xhtml dynamically. Is there any way to achieve this in java?

Comment: A bit vague. Do you want to emit the javascript while RENDERING the page, or do you want to attach the javascript to a page which has already been loaded?

Comment: I need to add it to a page that is already loaded . Moreover the script would reside in DB, so when i read , it would be in form of bytes. not sure how to attach this to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Answer based on the comment additions (you should update your question instead of commenting):

What you want happens mostly client-side, the only server side component would be for example a servlet which can pull the data from the database which you can then reference using for example JQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

I don't get your blob restriction, it makes more sense to use a clob.